# PHP in Docker: Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in /var/www/html/websocket/server.php on line 28

Tags: php, docker, php-7, php-socket

l'm using official images of PHP7, my docker start command: `docker run -p 9000:9000 --name php -v $site_path:/var/www/html/ --privileged=true -d php:php72`

`$site_path` is a directory that saving my php code, then l was into the docker container, use `php server.php` then got the warning above.

l also tried to run script without `9000` port like `9001`, then script worked, but l can't connect to the server with my JS

l tried to use `php server.php` on my local environment(not in docker)  and it worked, JS connected it successfully, too.

Comment: Doesn't xdebug use 9000 for itself.

Comment: l tried to modify command to `-p 9000:9000 -p 9001:9001` and change the port to `9001` in the code, the warning came again (when l not bind `9001` port in the docker command, the script could run)

Answer (score 0):

You have your port 9000 and 9001 already blocked by running containers or local software.

`docker ps` shows you all running containers and the port they block. If not needed, remove these container with `docker rm [-f] <name>`. If on Linux, you can check what else is running locally on port 9000/9001 by looking at `netstat -lnp`. Stop the processes, too.

Please note that you don't need to change the port in your container, if you want to try a new target port on host. You can also do: `-p9002:9000`, if you want a service accessible by port 9002 on your localhost.

Comment: this is what l want to do: execute `php server.php` in container. and if l want to communicate with docker, l need designated port mapping, so l use `-p 9000:9000`, but if l do this, it was wrong, and l tried your suggest, also failed

Comment: If the error message is `address already in use`, then the port is in use. Either by a process inside a docker container or outside. Do you start two servers in one container? Anyways, you should see all ports in use by `netstat -lnp`.